# Castle ILogger and lazy loading Func<string>

Tags: c#, nlog

So i am using the Castle built in support for logging and chosen to leverage NLog.

so have done some reading with NLog, it seems that previously you would want to always have any of your log messages wrapped in an if block to increase performance by not computing the value for the message unless it is actually needed. I get it, ugly but makes sense.

```
if (Logger.IsInfoEnabled)
{
      Logger.InfoFormat
      (
       "some info message with a process running for dates of {0} to {1}",
          fromDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
          toDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
      );
}
```

So digging in I notice that Logger.Info has an overload with (Func)
"Lazy loaded". GREAT, now i dont need to have all these if blocks everywhere =]

the question is (I'm still getting used to Func[ing] so go easy on me)
does this call get passed to the lazy load Func or does it get sent in as string?

```
 Logger.Info
     (string.Format(
        "some info message with a process running for dates of {0} to {1}",
        fromDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), 
        toDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
     ));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is missing some brackets to make it a `Func`

```
Logger.Info(() =>
    string.Format(
        "Check Pam Calendar for holidays for date range {0} to {1}", 
        fromDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), 
        toDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
     ));
```

And this is the correct way to write the code - the `string.Format` method will only get called if the `Logger` is going to log the string.